# Java JPanel movement (keylistener) not working

Tags: java, swing, controller, keylistener

> I've been trying to let an image move up and down in Jpanel for quite
>   a long while, but it never seems to work.
>
> If I put "y = y - 1" in the view, it makes the image move up, so I
>   guess the problem is with the keylistener, right?
>
> Could anyone help me with this please? To be honest... I think it will
>   be a very stupid mistake but I can't find how to get it to work.
>
> Extra information: I am using BlueJ to from it, with 4 classes in the
>   basic program for my question. I realize that a lot of people on the
>   internet said to use key bindings and not KeyListener but I don't
>   understand key bindings as for now...

--- Following the advice of Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I will try to use Keybindings. ---

So Keybindings has 2 'commands' to work: input and action.

Copied this code and changed it for my program:

```
protected void addBindings() {
   int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
   InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition); // What does this do?

   KeyStroke key = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, Event.KEY_PRESS);
   inputMap.put(key, move(0, 2));
```

The move function:

```
protected void beweeg (int dx, int dy)
{
    view.x = view.x + dx;
    view.y = view.y + dy;
}
```

I have to say... the code system on this forum is incredibly frustrating.
When trying this I get: "cannot find symbol - method getInputMap(int)"
Did I need to declare it somewhere? I don't see anything about this.

Comment: Please search the site for similar questions as this has been asked and answered many times. The gist: don't use a KeyListener but rather Key Bindings. Google can get you to the tutorials. And never call `repaint()` from within paintComponent -- that's not a safe way to animate. Use a Swing Timer instead.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried that before (Keybindings), It didn't work so I guess I'll ask a bit more here? If that's okay with you.

Comment: Oh, absolutely, please ask more, please edit your question. The more detail and pertinent code (but of course leaving out code not relevant to the problem) the better we will be able to help. So if you can, please post your Key Binding attempt. Best if you could post a [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to review, test, and possibly help you fix.

Comment: I prepared an answer for cases like yours - [How to use Key Bindings instead of Key Listeners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners), though there are many more dealing with this.

Comment: See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for complete working examples with Key Bindings.

Comment: @user1803551 From this moment: "private class MoveAction extends AbstractAction" I don't understand why it happens this way. Why create a new class just to move something? Why not just do X = X + 5;?

Comment: In your action map, you have to set an `Action`, you can't just write `X = X + 5`. That means you have to create a class for `Action`. Inside the `actionPreformed` of `MoveAction` you need to put your code, such as `X = X + 5`. If you do, each time you press the key which activates the action, you will execute `X = X + 5`.

Comment: My tutorial is more of a template into which you can insert your code. If you need full working examples see the links by camickr and HovercraftFullOfEels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> When trying this I get: "cannot find symbol - method getInputMap(int)" Did I need to declare it somewhere?

This method must be called on an object that derives from JComponent or one of its children such as a JPanel. This error message means that you're making this call inside of a class that does not extend JComponent or one of its children such as a JPanel. A possible solution is to call the method on the object that you want to attach the bindings to, on your JPanel object.

---

Speaking of links, here are some of mine: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23306438/522444), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254166/did-i-structure-this-key-listener-properly/23254218#23254218), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796767/my-jframe-is-not-changing-when-key-pressed/22796848#22796848), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730715/java-keyboard-input-game-development/22731033#22731033), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867283/method-keeps-window-from-closing/21867339#21867339), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817427/simple-program-with-keyadapter-cant-register-single-keys-after-pressing-down-se/21817447#21817447),...

Comment: Yes, found that out while using user1803551's guide :) thanks  
For other readers:
static JLabel obj1 = new JLabel();  
private static final int IFW = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
obj1.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), MOVE_UP);
obj1.getActionMap().put(MOVE_UP, boven());



honestly... writing on this forum isn't fun at all... I can't even put a nice comment without having to hassle it... ugh

Comment: @Java-questions: some links of my own are posted above with example code. And use of the forum will get easier with time, trust me.

Comment: @Java-questions, Don't use a static variable for the JLabel.

Comment: @Java-questions Better if you post code by editing your question instead of posting in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Keywords: driving rotating turning car

So after a long time of searching and the help of several forums I got the following result, to 'drive' cars and making 'smooth' turns.
Sorry for not using the code provided before, it helped me to understand a lot though. Thanks

I can't figure out how to use the coding on this forum, can anyone insert the following code please? thanks
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/1728

Maybe someone will be able to use it putting it online :)

Kind regards

Niels